# What're some global optimization algorithms that support categorical input?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

Are there any global optimization algorithms that support categorical input variables?

Evolutionary algorithms generally need to perform local mutation, however, unlike real or integer variables, it is hard to define similarity of categorical variables

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo For example, the function takes input like "apple", "orange" and "banana", and there's no order relationships between these values.

Comment: I assume there are finitely many categories. Say, $n$ categories. Why not have a bijection from the set of categories to the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, i.e., use integer labels?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I think if I encode categories into integers, then the algorithm may think there's an order relationship between different categories. For example, category 1 may be viewed as more similar tho category 2 than category 100.

Comment: Why not fix the category, solve an optimization problem for each (fixed) category and then take the optimum of those?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo What if there are more than one categorical variables, the combination would be explosively large

Comment: Why not have a Boolean vector to represent which categories are "in" and which are "out"?